# how to manage duplicate keys while reading text file in python

Tags: python, pandas

Source Data is  as below:

```
Name : ValueA
Age: 23
Height: 178cm
Friend : A
Friend : B
Name : ValueB
Age: 22
Height: 168cm
Weight: 80Kg
Friend : A
Friend : C
Name : ValueC
Age: 40
Height: 188cm
IQ: 150
Friend : D
```

Required Output

| Name | Age | Height | Weight | IQ | Friend1 | Friend2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ValueA | 23 | 178cm | NA | NA | A | B |
| ValueB | 22 | 168cm | 80kg | NA | A | C |
| ValueC | 40 | 188cm | NA | 150 | D | NA |

The code I am using is

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    t = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# Organise data
stuff = {}
index = 0
for line in t:
    key, value = line.split(": ")
    if "Name" in key:
        stuff[index] = {"Name": value}
        current_key = index
        index += 1
    else:
        stuff[current_key][key] = value

# create dataframe
result_df = pd.DataFrame(stuff).T
```

The issues is due to duplicate key values, "Friend" Only last value is being recognized.I am getting output as below:

| Name | Age | Height | Weight | IQ | Friend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ValueA | 23 | 178cm | NA | NA | A |
| ValueB | 22 | 168cm | 80kg | NA | C |
| ValueC | 40 | 188cm | NA | 150 | D |

Please note there are other duplicate key values as well. Name is the primary key. The rest of them should be able to handle duplicate key values.

Comment: It would be helpful if you upload more code such as reading csv and creating dataframe using pandas.

Comment: Is "Friend" the only key that could be repeated? Is it always going to appear 0, 1 or 2 times?

Comment: @Park Code updated.

Comment: @aaorssa Mate there can be other duplicate keys as well and it can be repeated more than 3 times (maximum 7 times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generalize my previous answer to any number of friends, we could store all the values of "Friend" in a list, and assign the elements of the "Friend" list to its own columns right before creating the dataframe:

1. Add this to your for loop to store "Friend"(s) in a list:

   ```
   elif "Friend" in key:
       if "Friend" not in stuff[current_key]:
           stuff[current_key]["Friend"] = list()
       stuff[current_key]["Friend"].append(value)
   ```
2. After your for loop, to create a new key for each "Friend" element:

   ```
   for key in stuff:
       for i, friend in enumerate(stuff[key]["Friend"], start=1):
           stuff[key][f"Friend{i}"] = friend
       del stuff[key]["Friend"]
   ```

Resulting code:

```
# Organise data
stuff = {}
index = 0
for line in t:
    key, value = line.split(": ")
    if "Name" in key:
        stuff[index] = {"Name": value}
        current_key = index
        index += 1
    elif "Friend" in key:
        if "Friend" not in stuff[current_key]:
            stuff[current_key]["Friend"] = list()
        stuff[current_key]["Friend"].append(value)
    else:
        stuff[current_key][key] = value

for key in stuff:
    for i, friend in enumerate(stuff[key]["Friend"]):
        stuff[key][f"Friend{i}"] = friend
    del stuff[key]["Friend"]

# create dataframe
result_df = pd.DataFrame(stuff).T
print(result_df)
```

---

**Part 2: Generalization to any key**

```
stuff = {}
index = 0
for line in t:
    key, value = line.split(": ")
    if "Name" in key:
        stuff[index] = {"Name": [value]}  # Always use a list as vale
        current_key = index
        index += 1
    elif key not in stuff[current_key]:  # If key does not exist
        stuff[current_key][key] = [value]  # Create key with value in a list
    else:
        stuff[current_key][key].append(value)  # If key exists, append the value

for key in stuff:
    for subkey in list(stuff[key].keys()):
        for i, element in enumerate(stuff[key][subkey], start=1):
            stuff[key][f"{subkey}{i}"] = element
        del stuff[key][subkey]

# create dataframe
result_df = pd.DataFrame(stuff).T
print(result_df)
```

Output:

```
    Name1 Age1 Height1 Friend 1 Friend 2 Weight1  IQ1
0  ValueA   23   178cm        A        B     NaN  NaN
1  ValueB   22   168cm        A        C    80Kg  NaN
2  ValueC   40   188cm        D      NaN     NaN  150
```

---

**Old answer** (not scalable)

You could add this `elif` inside your loop. The idea is to identify the "Friend" key but store two possible keys ("Friend1" and "Friend2"). We only use "Friend2" if "Friend1" already exists:

```
elif "Friend" in key:
    if "Friend1" not in stuff[current_key]:
        stuff[current_key]["Friend1"] = value
    elif "Friend2" not in stuff[current_key]:
        stuff[current_key]["Friend2"] = value
```

Notice that, if a row only has "Friend1", pandas should fill "Friend2" with a NaN value automatically.

Comment: Hi @aaossa this way I have to individually check for a lot of repeated keys which will make the code big.

Comment: @misguided updated my answer to generalize to any number of friends

Comment: Thanks aaossa, this is great, Is there a way we can modify the code to not hardcode friend but look for any duplicate keys and have the same enumeration concept?

Comment: Yes, just change "Friend" to `key`. Also, you'll have to change the second loop to work with any key, and instead of store the values as is, you'll have to always use a list. I'll leave all the changes as a part 2 in my answer.

Comment: This is awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Is there any trick to stop Pandas frm sorting the keys alphabetically?  The results looks perfect before converting it into dataframe. Oncethe data is in dataframe, it gets sorted alphabetically accoring to the keys and loses the sorting in the original question

Comment: I'm not sure that its possible, and is even harder on part 2, because the column names would be different. Maybe if you use `for subkey in sorted(stuff[key].keys()):` instead the dict keys will remain in the same order from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the value of the key to a list, if a key has no value you can set it to `None`.

```py
stuff = {}
index = 0
for line in t:
    key, value = line.split(": ")
    if "Name" in key:
        stuff[index] = {"Name": value}
        current_key = index
        index += 1
    else:
        if key in list(stuff[current_key].keys()): #Check existing value
            new_value = []
            if type(stuff[current_key][key]) is list:
                for x in stuff[current_key][key]:
                    new_value.append(x)
            else:
                new_value.append(stuff[current_key][key])
            new_value.append(value)
            stuff[current_key][key] = new_value
        else: #No existing value
            stuff[current_key][key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle duplicate keys in Python, use a data structure that permits multiple values, like a dict of lists.  For example:

```py
# Organise data
stuff = {}
index = 0
for line in t:
    key, value = line.split(": ")
    if "Name" in key:
        stuff[index] = {"Name": value}
        current_key = index
        index += 1
    else:
        stuff[current_key].setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

In this code, setdefault sets the value for `key` to an empty list (if not already set), and then you immediately append to it.  This means that all keys (except Name) will have a list of values instead of a single value.

Another approach, which I prefer, is not to dictify things.  You have a schema, so you can have a dataclass.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
    height: str
    weight: str
    friends: list
    iq: int

people = []
cur_person = None
for line in t:
    key, value = [i.strip() for i in line.split(":", 1)]
    if key == 'Name':
        cur_person = Person(value, age=None, height=None, weight=None,
                            friends=[], iq=None)
        people.append(cur_person)
    elif key in {'Age', 'IQ'}:
        setattr(cur_person, key.lower(), int(value))
    elif key == 'Friend':
        cur_person.friends.append(value)
    else:
        setattr(cur_person, key.lower(), value)
```

Comment: I understand the approach, but looking at having duplicate keys renamed so that I can analyse the same in excel. The issue with having list of values for a key is , it is difficult to work with in excel :(

Comment: The dict-of-lists approach is a natural representation of duplicate keys that applies in many circumstances.  You can then transform it into whatever Excel representation you like.